# need to display all the photos as thumbnails in one window from my photolibrary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, save, photos

i need to display  all the photos as thumbnails in one window from my photolibrary?is there any tool to display all?How can i do it?also i need to select photos from the displayed window and save the selected item  to AppBundle with the user given name.could tell me in the correct way to do it and if possible any sample code to get my started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a detailed question, that really has a lot more to do with how you want to design your app, however, I can answer part of the technical aspect.

To show your photo library, you use the `UIImagePickerController` class, and display it, with something like:

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
```

Then you implement the delegate method:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
```

This method is called when the user finishes picking an image from the displayed UIImagePickerController. Here is where you can save the image to the bundle or present a new screen to name it or whatever you want to do. For saving an image to the bundle take a look at: [save an image](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=156818).  Also for more info on UIImagePickerController, take a look at its [Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could the three20 photo library viewer application.

Check below link to know [How to use the three20 photo viewer](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer)

Check the blog tutorial for displaying all the photos as thumbnails.

http://trailsinthesand.com/picking-images-with-the-iphone-sdk-uiimagepickercontroller/

Comment: Looks like he just needs to display from the photo library on the phone, but if he means an online photo library, three20 is the way  to go.